Easy to use software or games for creating custom 3d map/scenes?
I've been creating memory palaces using various software and games. In short I create a unique map and store information on various locations and structures to help me memorise things. So far I have tried Blender, SketchUp, Minecraft, Fallout 4, GTA 5, etc. I've found Minecraft usable as it's easy to build maps and put up signs, except it lacks too much in graphics. It's all blocks and I can't easily import 3d assets from elsewhere, even then, it wouldn't fit with the voxelated environment.
So what are some of the software/games that allows you to build custom scenes/maps freely? Real-time rendering and exploration (walking) is greatly preferred.

Garry's Mod sounds like the perfect tool for your use-case.  It's a sandbox built on the same engine as Half-life 2.  It's a bit like Forge-mode in Halo; you have assets you can place in the world, and design your own 3D space.  I know you can import your own assets as well, though I don't know the details as to how to do that.  You can also download tons of them from the steam workshop, there's thousands to choose from.
You can find the game on Steam here, or in the Steam client store.
